# MVC Partial View in Layout Page in Webforms Application giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webforms application and I have created a MVC View and a Layout Page and I have also created a Partial View but it is giving an error while loading in Layout Page. Please see the following error and my code:

Error on _LayoutPage.cshtml

[image: Error on _LayoutPage.cshtml]

I have added my code bellow:

_LayoutPage.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Bellow table is in Layout page(Master Page)</p>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td>@{Html.RenderAction("_Header", "Layout"); }</td>
            <td>@RenderBody()</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

LayoutController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CBT_WebApplication.Library.CS;
using CBT_WebApplicationProject.Models;

namespace CBT_WebApplicationProject.Controllers
{
    public class LayoutController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult _Header()
        {
            HeaderVM hvm = new HeaderVM();
            hvm.sAltText = "HFI Logo";
            hvm.sHomeURL = "~/Home3.aspx";
            hvm.sClass = "logo-header";
            hvm.sLogoSrc = "/images/graphics/hf-logo-header-blue.png";

            return PartialView("~/Views/Header/_Header.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

_Header.cshtml (Partial View)

```
@model CBT_WebApplicationProject.Models.HeaderVM

    <div id="divHFI" class='@Model.sClass'>
        <a href='@Model.sHomeURL'>
            <img src='@Model.sLogoSrc' alt='@Model.sAltText' />
        </a>
    </div>
```

HeaderVM.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CBT_WebApplicationProject.Models
{
    public class HeaderVM
    {
        public string sAltText { get; set; }
        public string sHomeURL { get; set; }
        public string sLogoSrc { get; set; }
        public string sClass { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

Comment: @VDWWD My question is not specifically related to NullReferenceException
Please review my question again as this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55294184/8561847) has solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass your model when you return PartialView in controller in your case its

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Header/_Header.cshtml",hvm);
```

that will do it

Comment: Thanks. It worked (y)